# Porque posso invocar funções sem parênteses no VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, sintaxe

Em C#, este código não compila:

```
public static string Teste(){
    string val = "";
    return val.Trim;
}
```

Porque a função `Teste` requer um retorno do tipo `string`, e `Trim` é um `MethodGroup`. Isso faz todo sentido na minha opinião.

Porém, no VB.NET, esta função funciona perfeitamente:

```
Public Function Teste() as String
    Dim valor as String = ""
    Return valor.Trim
End Function
```

Porque a invocação de funções no VB não precisa dos parênteses? Consigo passar  parâmetros para funções invocadas dessa maneira? Afinal, existe diferença entre invocar com ou sem parênteses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se alguém vai conseguir responder algo melhor do que: é assim porque foi definido assim. Quem desenvolveu a linguagem achou que era uma boa ideia e decidiram que assim que seria feito.

Declaração de *sub procedures* também têm isto, você pode criá-las como `Sub Teste` ou `Sub Teste()`.

> Consigo passar parâmetros para funções invocadas dessa maneira?

Não. Os parênteses só são opcionais para funções que não pedem parâmetros (tanto para declarar quanto para invocar).

```vb
Sub Teste           ' Ok, não tem parâmetros, não precisa de parênteses
Sub Teste()         ' Também é correto.
Sub Te(x as String) ' Precisa de parênteses, por causa dos parâmetros

obj.Teste           ' Ok, não tem parâmetros, não precisa de parênteses
obj.Teste()         ' Mas você pode usálos, de qualquer maneira
obj.Te("A")         ' Precisa de parênteses para passar o parâmetro
```

> Afinal, existe diferença entre invocar com ou sem parênteses?

Nenhuma. Isto é puramente sintaxe.